# Yield return database records using LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a supplying method in DAL:

```
public IEnumerable<RecordType> GetRecords()
{
    using (LinqDataContext context = new LinqDataContext())
    {
        var records = context.RecordTable;

        foreach (RecordType record in records)
        {
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer method uses the records in a `foreach` loop. This way I want to save a memory usage by not caching all the records from `RecordTable`, since LinqToSql uses a DataReader behind the scene.

I have two questions on this scenario though:

1. Is that true that yield-returning above saves resources and works faster than caching all records to an array (.ToArray())?
2. Will the data connection be automatically properly closed (I mean the `using` statement) if an error will occur inside the `foreach` loop of the consuming method OR if the consuming method will break the `foreach` loop in the middle (like found a required record and `break`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of executing a basic query, it *can* work that way (certainly it is possible) - however, in the case of querying a naked `Table<T>`, it *might* be that it all buffers first; you could perhaps try querying the count during the iteration, or running a trace. In this case I *suspect* it will buffer first.

Re closed: that also depends ;p If someone is using `foreach`, then yes: since `foreach` explicitly disposes the iterator via `finally`. However! It is not guaranteed if someone does, for example (very naughty and lax):

```
var iter = yourData.GetEnumerator();
if(iter.MoveNext()) {
    Console.WriteLine(iter.Current.Name); // first record of, say, 20
}
// and don't dispose the iterator == bad
```

then since the iterator doesn't a: get disposed, b: exhaust itself, and c: doesn't crash, it won't shut down properly (any of those 3 conditions *will* close it properly). Emphasis: this is a pathological case: normally it is reasonably safe to say "it will close, yes".

If you want guaranteed non-buffering, note that "dapper" has that, if you set `buffered` to `false`:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = connection.Query<Customer>(
       "select * from Customer", buffered: false);
```

(it can also handle the parameters etc)

Answer (score 3):

1) `yield` will not necessarily be faster to get all values, but it would allow the code to start handling results before the database has returned all results. That is, yield returns the first result the instant it shows up, while ToArray() needs to wait for all results to show up before returning. Of course, if the underlying providers return all results at once due to buffering or other reasons, this may not make a difference.

2) Yes, `using` will dispose of the LinqDataContext no matter how you exit the using block (exceptions/return/break/...)

Comment: Actually, 2 is "as long as the caller behaves properly" - it isn't strictly as "guaranteed" as most `using` are

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm assuming you're talking about not (correctly) enumerating the complete Enumerable, or am I missing something else?

Comment: yes, manually walking the iterator, and doing it incorrectly. It isn't a problem when using `foreach`, which most sane people will use.

Answer (score 2):

1. The iterator will be lazily evaluated. It will pull the first item and then "yield" it to its consumer. Performance impact will depend on how the LinqDataContext is implemented (it may cache stuff internally). Using ToArray(), or ToList(), will force all elements out of LinqDataContext before proceeding. Therefore, using ToArray() will make you yield nothing until LinqDataContext has returned every element. Whether that is optimal or not, is up to you.
2. Yes, the "using" will be enforced properly.